# image segmentation

Tags: matlab

i want to compute segmentation accuracy of split and merge algorithm using matlab. can someone suggest some idea ?

Comment: but you should change the title of this POST

Answer (score 2):

I hope these articles will help for you!

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12711-level-set-for-image-segmentation

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-source.html

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/43883774/MATLAB-SOURCE-CODE-FOR-IMAGE-SEGMENTATION

http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Image-Galleries/Image-Tools/Image-Segmentation---Extraction-54590.html

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8031-image-segmentation-extraction

http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html